# Input field not submitted in form when added through JS

Tags: 8, forms, javascript, ajax

I have a form that is processed first by an external service through JS and afterwards adds an input field to the form:

```
$('#my-form').once('submit').submit(function(e) {
  // some processing
...
  form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="token" />').attr('value', token.id));
  form.unbind();
  form.submit();
});
```

The field is added and also has the correct value. But when it is submitted the field is not present in neither my
 `public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)` **nor** in `public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)`.

I already tried using a textfield instead of type hidden, and hide it with css, but same result

Comment: Field added like that using **JS** will not be present in **PHP** functions validateForm or submitForm. Instead you can add a field type hidden in `buildForm` then update the value using JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden field in `buildForm()` like below

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  :
  :
  $form['token'] = [
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => ''
  ]; 
  :
  :
}
```

or, if you're not building the form yourself, i.e. you're altering an already existing form, you can add the hidden field via [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.5.x) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.5.x).

Then update value of it using **JS** if needed

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. But why does it behave like this? Why is the field not recognized when added through JS?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way we can add a field in to the form through JS in that way. There was a link in the previous answer for dynamic field creation through AJAX https://www.ondrupal.com/learn-drupal/creating-ajax-add-more-drupal-8

Comment: Because the form api tracks the form structure. Injecting a field with JavaScript does nothing. When it’s rebuilt or submitted it’s lost. You’ll want to add it as stated or via hook form alter if this isn’t your form you coded yourself.